# Taking Facebook permission before uploading app to the store?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

I am developing an application that requires publishing to Facebook.
However, in order to take the permission (publish_action) from Facebook, it is required to provide the store link for iOS and Google play link or an.apk for android version.

My application is currently under construction phase and I can't upload my application to the store without the Facebook permission!
So how could i take the permission before uploading my application to the store?

Comment: Are you trying to use FB login in your app?

Comment: You can get the iTunes link from iTunes connect although it will be a dead link until your first release. I believe there is a process documented somewhere for sending an ad hoc build to Facebook for testing

Comment: You don’t need to get your permissions reviewed while you are still developing the app (that would not even make sense, since when you submit for review they already want to see the functionality of your app, so you need to have developed and tested it by that time already) – you can ask every user that has a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for any permission, without prior review.

Comment: @DroidAks yes i am using FB login

Comment: @Paulw11  can you please provide me a link for that? I can't find anything related in Facebook developer site so i can send them a testing app

Comment: @IphoneUser then you dont need to take permissions. You can start developing the app. Once you upload the APK on play store then you should provide the path. Leave the link field blank.

Comment: @CBroe i already test it my app using an admin role, now i want to release it to the store. And to do that it is required to have this permission when it is released. so i need to take the permission first so users will be able to use my app when it is available on the store.

Comment: @DroidAks i want the permission before releasing the app to the store since my app functionality depends on that. It is mandatory to have the permission in case user will be able to normally use the application

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply :) Feel free to write your feedback in the answers section so i can mark it as an answer.